# If element contains certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.test').css('background','red');

<div id="example">Some text</div>
```

How can I `.addClass('test')` if `#example` contains the word "text"?

Comment: What have you tried? Frankly, this seems like a really, really straightforward use of the jQuery API.

Comment: **1.** Take the question tittle, add "jquery" before it. "jquery if element contains certain text"  **2.** Go to google and run the search.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

just use `:contains` pseudoclass

```
$('#example:contains("text")').addClass('test');
```

this will add the class to `#example` if it contains 'text'

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$("#example")` to get a jQuery wrapper for the element, then use `text()` to get its text, and use `String#indexOf`, e.g.:

```
var ex = $("#example");
if (ex.text().indexOf("text") !== -1) {
    ex.addClass("test");
}
```

You can also use `:contains("text")` in the selector as [F. Calderan shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10329507/157247), although note that when you use non-standard pseudo-selectors like that, jQuery can't use the underlying browser's built-in stuff for finding elements, so it can be slower. The above will allow jQuery to use `document.getElementById`. There are only a few situations where the speed really matters, though.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code

```
$('#example:contains("text")').addClass('test');
```

Have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) for examples and explanations of the `:contains` selector