# How to get an input based on a string inside a div via jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If element contains certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329477/if-element-contains-certain-text)

I have this **(updated)** html:

```
<div>
    <div class="checkBox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" class="NS" value="n"  />
    </div>
    No Sauce                    
</div>

<div>
    <div class="checkBox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" class="NC" value="x"  />
    </div>
    No Cheese                    
</div>

<div>
    <div class="checkBox checkBoxSelected">
        <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" class="no_submit" checked="checked" value=""  />
    </div>
    Regular Cheese                    
</div>

<div>
    <div class="checkBox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" class="no_submit" value=""  />
    </div>
    Regular Sauce                    
</div>
```

How can I (via jquery) get the input type that's inside the div containing the text "Regular Cheese"?

I know I can get all checkboxes like this:

```
$("input.no_submit:checkbox")
```

And I understand that if I want to affect the parent div of the item, I could do this:

```
$("input.no_submit:checkbox").parent("div").removeClass("checkBoxSelected");
```

I can get the actual text like this:

```
​var myText = $("div").text();
```

But I can't figure out how to combine them so that I can set a var that points to the actual input element inside the nested div which is itself inside a classless div whose text is a specific string.

Comment: This isn't really an exact duplicate; the issue isn't just finding the text inside the div, which I already indicated I could do. The problem is getting the input element inside a nested div based on the text inside the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Or bit different demo here: `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/NBGBP/

Hope it fits the need!

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.no_submit').click(function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert('Div text ==> ' + $(this).parents('div').text());   
        }

    });
});​
```

Comment: I like this answer best - `:contains()` is too slow, and so is grabbing every `div` in the page and checking for specific text based on a nodeType filter! +1 `:)`

Comment: @ahren `:)` you sire are a legend and a good human! A coffee shout whenever we meet! Thanks bruv! Cheers for noticing the details as well!

Comment: The problem with this one is that the class of the checkboxes will not always be no_submit.

Comment: @EmmyS in that case do this please `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/4TMV7/ demo should help - http://jsfiddle.net/4TMV7/

Answer (score 1):

You can do a filter with :contains() to find the "Regular Cheese" text. Separating this into filter instead of doing div:contains will be a faster selector. You then want to find the input that is in the parent div and print out it's type.

```
$("div").filter(":contains('Regular Cheese')")
    .find("input.no_submit").prop("type");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZeSdV/1/

Comment: Well, it sort of works. I forked your fiddle [(new fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/CFeah/) and updated with slightly more code, and it finds and affects all inputs with class of no_submit, not just ones that are inside a div containing the Regular Cheese text.

Comment: Sorry I updated the code snippet but not the fiddle when I realized that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div:contains("Regular Cheese") input.no_submit')
```

reference:

contains - http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Demo: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/Fs9tK/