# Find div by text and delete text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I find div that contains specific text and delete this text from div.For example

```
<div>
DeleteText
<span>Something text</span>
<div>Something span inner text </div>
</div>
```

I need find div **by text**(DeleteText in example) and delete only this text from div.How can I do it.

Only DeleteText should be removed. All other html element and contents should be left as they are.

Comment: Really, please read this before coming to stackoverflow... http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DSelectors%26redirect%3Dno 

direct answer on jQuery site... (specifically http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show you've at least attempted this yourself, because we're not here to do your job for you, nor here to teach you basics.

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329477/if-element-contains-certain-text

Comment: @jholloman actually not, because, he wants to delete the text content alone.

Comment: @atredis next time when you post a question please try to explain a bit more. so that everyone can understand and help you out.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum I just find solution that present Praveen Kumar or vega.There isn't answer on jQuery site

Comment: @Marc B,I think it is not a basis

Comment: @atredis did you even click my links? the :contains selector which I sent you towards is EXACTLY what you were looking for with exactly what you want to accomplish as a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**:contains**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to select the div and then filter the contents and remove the node.

```
$("div:contains('DeleteText')").contents().filter(function () {
    return (this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) == 'DeleteText');
}).remove();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YkEy5/

Comment: @atredis You didn't mean to `remove()` the element from the DOM I suppose! Please clear your question!!!

Answer (score 2):

#### You need to use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector for this.

You can find the `DeleteText` by:

```
$("div:contains('DeleteText')").html("");
```

For removing **just the text**, you can use this function:

```
function removeText(element){
    var newElement = $('<' + element[0].nodeName + '/>');
    element.children().each(function(){
        newElement.append(this);
    });
    element.replaceWith(newElement);
}
```

Now **combining both**, you get this:

```
removeText($("div:contains('DeleteText')"));
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DwTmp/

Comment: Ok.But How can I delete this text.

Comment: @atredis Added the answer! Please check! :)

Comment: I need that div contains all except deleted text

Comment: @atredis Updated the answer. Please check! `:)`

Comment: Thanks.Еhis is what I had in mind

Comment: @atredis I have also added a fiddle, which you can check it out! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

:contains()

The documentation for this selector is here:
http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

`$('div:contains("something span inner text")');` should find your div item

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div:contains('DeleteText')").html('');
```

> The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in
>   any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with
>   attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains()
>   can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. The
>   text must have matching case to be selected.

Comment: I need that div contains everuthing except DeleteText

Answer (score 0):

Try this below

```
$('div:contains("sometext")').html('')
```

This looks for div with 'sometext' and puts empty text

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery:

```
$("div[innerHTML=Something inner text]")
```